# Does using an archive alleviate the overhead of loading many small files?

Tags: optimization, file-io, filesystems, compression, archive

I have a lot of small files to load, and I'm concerned about file IO performance.  I'm debating whether or not I should be using files that aggregate the data that will be related; for example, whether I should have "item.data" and "item.png", or just "item.data" (where the latter file contains the .png image data that would have been in "item.png").

The kicker is, I plan to load these files from an archive (either .7z or .zip), and I'm not sure whether or not I'm wasting my time.  I'm not really worried about the absolute data bandwidth between the disc and memory, I'm really just out to minimize seeks.  If these two files are stored in the same folder within the archive, will their data be contiguous?  If not, will the performance be improved for some other reason?

I'm not overly concerned about compression rates for the small files; despite having many (thousands) of these files, they'll pale in comparison to the other, larger files I'm working with.  I'm really just worried about seek times.

Will storing and loading the files with an archive solve the problems I'm worried about?  If it wont, what are some other approaches to help alleviate seek times and improve file IO performance?

Comment: Sounds like premature optimization to me.  Is the access to these small files really a bottleneck?  How much of one?  How much actually is seek-driven?  Measure, then optimize.

Comment: If you are concerned about I/O performance and overheads, ideally you should be tuning the file system to a smaller block size, in this way the metadata (maps, no of inodes) would be larger and would eventually improve I/O performance. Smaller block size would also avoid internal fragmentation.

Comment: @askb That would be what I should aim for when implementing a virtual filesystem (ie zip archives), correct?

Comment: Creating zip archives for improving I/O performance may not help.  For instance, every time the application needs to read a 1 file among 100000 small files in a zip archive. You would end up reading the whole archive, and verifying the compression headers or checksum of the archive and only then looking for a file within the archive. First, its best to provide more information on what the application does and what is the underlying FS. Also its best to identify the bottlenecks of the underlying FS and then optimize I/O performance, followed by tuning the application.

Comment: @askb Memory-mapping the archvie allows me to only load the parts of it that I need.  This way I can load in the information about how the archive's files are structured and where they're located, grab those offsets, and use them to only load the files I actually need.  .zip might not be appropriate for this, but that's more or less what I'm looking for.

Comment: Its going to be pretty complex going about this way, as you would required reading the data structures of the compressed archive file (to understand how its stored) then determine the offset within archive. Next, actually mmap the archive and decompress the file. This simply added more overhead, unless you have a very application specific requirement in doing this!

Comment: The idea is to mmap the archive at load time, get the offsets, then load in the already-mmapped files and decompress them at runtime.  Some overhead during startup would be worth the (potentially considerable) speedups during runtime. Note that I haven't measured so I can't define "potentially considerable".  Hence, this question.